# Insert into foreign table partition doesn't work

Tags: postgresql, mariadb, database-partitioning, postgres-fdw, mysql-fdw

I have some table in mariadb.

I need to create foreign table partition for that table

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (  
  id serial NOT NULL, 
  name varchar(30)
) partition by range(id);

CREATE foreign TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_p 
  partition of users for values from(0) to (10000) 
SERVER test22 
options (table_name 'users');
```

If i try to get some data all is OK

but then i try insert something

```
insert into users (id,name) values (111,'somename');
```

I got an error (text depends on fdw)

> COPY and foreign partition routing not supported in mysql_fdw

i tried two variants of fdw.

EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw and pgspider/jdbc_fdw

Is there a fdw that supports insert if foreign table is partition? Or any variants how can i realize that

Comment: Changed the postgres-fdw tag to mysql-fdw to match what is reported in the question.

Comment: You might want to add a comment to this issue [Partition INSERT](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw/issues/250).

Comment: This post says that foreign keys are not allowed on partitioned tables in mysql. Is it the same in mariaDB?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537219/how-to-handle-foreign-key-while-partitioning

Answer (score 0):

pgspider/mysql_fdw - solves my problem